# Drag and Drop Only Won't Work on Chromebook

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, chromebook

I am creating a website with a drop down menu that allows a user to drag icons from the menu into a table, but when I drag the icon from the menu to the table the ondragover function does not begin, as if nothing is being dragged over. This problem only happens when I am using a Chromebook. When I tried this on a PC, I was able to drag the icon over without any problem. I used console.log to see if the function was ever running, and it does when I drag an icon that is not within the menu, but not when in the menu.

What would be causing this problem, and how would I go about fixing it.

Also, this is a chromebook issued by my school, so is there a possibility that it is the school restriction acting on the code?

Comment: Interesting... Can you post a little code snippet of the drag/drop code?  I can't say I've ever used a chromebook, but I doubt that the school is restricting website drag & drop.  That would be unlikely.

Comment: @JohnGrese Here is the link to the site, you can check the source code to see what is going on... [thimbleprojects.org/ncameron/429089]